# Counting groups with shared elements

Tags: r

I have a data set which looks like below:

```
Comp1  Product  Comp2
A       P1      B
A       P2      B
A       P3      B
C       P4      D
C       P2      D
X       P1      Y
X       P2      Y
X       P3      Y
```

So basically, `Comp1` and `Comp2` are the companies and `Product` is the product name that these companies have in common. I want the output to appear something like this:

```
Product Bundle    Count
P1,P2,P3          2
P2,P4             1
```

I am new to R and would appreciate any help in this case.

Comment: I don't understand your result.

Comment: How did you get `Count`?

Comment: A and B both share products P1, P2, P3. Same for X and Y. That's 2 company pairs that share that bundle.
C and D share P2 and P4. That's 1.

Comment: The companies A and B have 3 products common to them, those would be P1, P2,P3 and also same products are common to X and Y.
Hence the product bundle p1,p2,p3 has been common to A-B and X-Y 
so the count comes to 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can summarize the data then count it. For example

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% arrange(Comp1, Product) %>% 
  group_by(Comp1) %>% 
  summarize(bundle=paste(unique(Product), collapse=",")) %>% 
  count(bundle)

#     bundle     n
#      <chr> <int>
# 1 P1,P2,P3     2
# 2    P2,P4     1
```

with the test data

```
dd <- read.table(text="Comp1  Product  Comp2
A       P1      B
A       P2      B
A       P3      B
C       P4      D
C       P2      D
X       P1      Y
X       P2      Y
X       P3      Y", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Typo in your first word, fyi. Base R analogue: `with(aggregate(Product ~ Comp1, dd[order(dd$Product), ], toString), data.frame(table(Product)))`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks a lot, i was trying the summarize option but couldn't get the count working earlier. Appreciate your quick help :)

Comment: Thanks @Frank I was trying to figure out how to do this in base.

Comment: Isn't this just counting the number of unique combinations for Comp1 though, or am I mistaken? @MrFlick

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[order(Product), Prod.Bundle := toString(Product), by = Comp1
         ][, .(Count = uniqueN(Comp2)), by = Prod.Bundle]
```

Or another as provided by @Frank in the comments:

```
setDT(d)[order(Product), toString(Product), by = Comp1
         ][, .(Count = .N), by = .(Prod.Bundle = V1)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Prod.Bundle Count
> 1:  P1, P2, P3     2
> 2:      P2, P4     1
> ```

---

Used data:

```
d <- read.table(text="Comp1  Product  Comp2
A       P1      B
A       P2      B
A       P3      B
C       P4      D
C       P2      D
X       P1      Y
X       P2      Y
X       P3      Y", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer using base r as I do, this is an idea:

```
dtb <- table(paste(dd[[1]],dd[[3]]),dd[[2]])
out <- sapply(1:nrow(dtb),function(x) paste(colnames(dtb)[dtb[x,] == 
1],collapse = ","))
table(out)
out
P1,P2,P3    P2,P4 
       2        1
```

Comment: How would you expand this to accommodate another column, say Comp3? I'm trying it out and getting an incorrect number of dimensions error.

Comment: Just add said column into the paste function.

Comment: I did, as `dd[[4]]` after `dd[[3]]`, didn't change anything to the `sapply` line. Prints out `Error in `[.default`(dtb, x, ) : incorrect number of dimensions`. But it works if I move it between `dd[[1]]` and `dd[[3]]`, or at the front. My new column is a factor with same number of elements, but 5 levels, opposed to 3, if that matters. `dd$Comp3 <- as.factor(c("E", "E", "F", "G", "H", "Z", "Z", "Z"))`

Comment: Hmm. It's working for me. `paste()` should convert your factors to character class so I can't imagine that being an issue. Shouldn't matter where you put within `paste` either. Maybe there was a typo your first go around?

Comment: Hm, dunno. I just cleared my workspace and ran it all again and it worked. Thanks though.